# JSON pipe in Angular 2 is not working

Tags: json, angular, typescript

When I try to pipe my data by JSON pipe I get the following error in the console:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'json' could not be found (...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 72):

Most likely you forgot about importing `CommonModule`:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [ CommonModule ]
    ...
})
```

As noted in the comments, do this in the module where you're using the `json` pipe.

Comment: For context, this needs to be done in the module that declares the component which uses the json pipe.

Comment: For angular 9: Ensure your component is registered in module's declarations.

Comment: ...and make sure that Module is imported in AppModule @ gio

Answer (score 29):

In my case `CommonModule` was added, but the component was not part of declaration of any module

(I was creating component dynamically by using `ContainerRef`)

Comment: @WasifKhalil I added the component to it's module declaration, if you don;'t have any add it to app.moudle declarations

Comment: If you're here, be sure to double-check your component is actually imported into the module you think it is.

Answer (score 8):

Your parent Module of the component should be like this.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {AuditTrailFilterComponent} from './components/audit-trail-filter/audit-trail-filter.component';

import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common'; <-- This is important !!!!

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule, <-- This is important !!!!
  ],
  declarations: [AuditTrailFilterComponent],
  exports: [
    AuditTrailFilterComponent
  ]
})
export class AuditTrailModule {
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the second word of your post 'parent'.  That was the light bulb moment I needed after hours of struggles!

Answer (score 0):

This can also occur if you declare your component in a [Lazy module](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) and try to add the component to a route that hasn't caused that module to be loaded.

eg. I just had this error with:

```
children: [

     {
         path: 'editor',
         loadChildren: () => from(import(/* webpackChunkName: "editor" */ '../editor/editor.module').then(m => m.EditorModule))
     },

     { 
         path: 'multi-preview',
         component: MultiPreviewerComponent    // declared in Editor.module (lazy loaded)
     }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For me,

I had to add it on the under the providers in the app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        { provide: JsonPipe },  <-- This is important !!!!
```