# Angular2 module component giving me error pipe can not be found

Tags: javascript, angular2-routing

Angular2 module component giving me error pipe can not be found

`{{obj|json}}`

pipe json can not be found.
What is the possible reason for the error?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389309/json-pipe-in-angular-2-is-not-working

Comment: I read about it and tried it but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the test code and it simply works :

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  obj : any = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];

}
```

app.component.html

```
{{ obj |  json }}
```

browser output

[ "test1", "test2", "test3" ]

You can paste the code here, so that we can check where exactly you are missing on pipe.

You can check more information on Jsonpipe here

https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe

Comment: I have two modules in my project and it is working fine in components of one module, but it is not working in components of the other modules.

Comment: can you paste your code in here or on plunker, so  to check possible errors?

Comment: I found that I was using component in third module and that module was not have CommonModule in it and it was creating problems. Thanks it is working now,

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was just restarting the application and it worked.